# How do I get request parameters into query criteria?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, ejb, cdi

I've been reading everything I can get my hands on about JSF2 and Weld scopes.  I think I've read almost everything BalusC has written on the subject and I still can't figure this out.  Didn't want you guys to think I wasn't trying hard on my own to get this.

I have a very simple app with search page and result page. (the real app is way bigger than this "test" app with something like 20 parameters)  There are 2 RequestScoped beans, one that backs the search and one that backs the result.  There is one EJB that takes the input, creates a query and returns a list of matching entities to the result.

I have 1 problem and 1 question.  The problem is my attempts to get the parameter values from the search to the result are not working.  I've seen this pattern used frequently, but my attempts to get it to work are failing.

The question is.... what is the best way to get the parameters from the search page to the EJB where they will be used as part of the query.  Am I supposed to be abel to access the request parameter map from an EJB?  I have tried that and not been successful -- not sure if it's something I'm doing or if this is simply not supposed to be possible. Is this EJB supposed to be Stateful or Stateless?

Search.xhtml

```
<html>

<h:head></h:head>

<h:form>

    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="Hostname" />
        <h:inputText value="#{deviceSearch.hostname}" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:commandButton action="#{deviceSearch.navigate('devices')}"
        value="Devices Page">
        <f:param name="hostname" value="#{deviceSearch.hostname}" />
    </h:commandButton>

    <h:button value="Reset" immediate="true" type="reset" />


</h:form>
</html
```

Results.xhtml

```
<html>
<h:head></h:head>

<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="hostname" value="#{deviceResult.hostname}"></f:viewParam>
</f:metadata>

<h:form>
<h:button value="Return to Search" includeViewParams="false" outcome="index" />
</h:form>

<h:dataTable value="#{deviceResult.deviceList}" var="device">
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputText value="Device is #{device.name}" />
    <h:outputText value="dev id is #{device.devId}" />
    <h:outputText value="os is #{device.os}" />
    <h:outputText value="platform is #{device.platform}" />
</h:panelGrid>

</h:dataTable>

</html>
```

DeviceSearch.java

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class DeviceSearch {


    // Search terms
    String hostname;

    public String getHostname() {
        return hostname;
    }

    public void setHostname(String hostname) {  
        this.hostname = hostname;
    }

    public String navigate(String className) {

        if (className.equals("devices")) {
            return "result.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

DeviceResult.java

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class DeviceResult {

    @Inject DeviceService deviceListService;


    String hostname;

    public void init(){
        deviceList = deviceListService.fetchDevices(hostname);
    }

    public String getHostname() {
        return hostname;
    }

    public void setHostname(String hostname) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
    }


    // Results
    List<Devices> deviceList = new ArrayList<Devices>();

    public List<Devices> getDeviceList() {
        deviceList = deviceListService.fetchDevices(hostname);
        return deviceList;
    }
}
```

DeviceService.java

```
@Stateful
public class DeviceService {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public DeviceService() {
    }

    String hostname;
    List<Devices> devicesList = new ArrayList<Devices>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Devices> fetchDevices(String hostname) {
        Query qry = em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Devices d WHERE d.name=:name");
        qry.setParameter("name", hostname);
        devicesList = qry.getResultList();
        return devicesList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should use a _conversation scoped bean_ or a _session scoped bean_ to hold the results of your search.  Also, there's no need for the param tag in your search form.  The fact that your text input is bound to `deviceSearch.hostName` is enough to make sure the property is set in your backing bean (the _setHost_ setter will get invoked automatically when the form is submitted by the user).  Also, your `navigate` method is quite odd and seemingly uneccessary.  Navigation should be handled by returning an _outcome_ from your bean action that refers to an entry in `navigation.xml` file.

Comment: You should buy a book on JSF 2!  If you buy a book and spend a day reading it from the beginning, all of this stuff will make a lot more sense.  If you're bouncing all over the internet reading random information out of order and out of context, I assure you things will remain confusing for you.

Comment: the navigate() method makes more sense in the context of the whole soon to be app where there are many more possibilities than just 1 outcome.  @jahroy I'm sure you're right about the book and the pitfalls of bouncing all over the internet. Truly what I would love is a class -- I learn much better and very quickly in that venue than by reading, but I can't personally afford such a thing and my employer will not sponsor this as java web app development is the not the actual mission of my group.

Comment: I recommend [this book](http://old.zeta-zone.org/downloads/documents/Prentice.Hall.Core.JavaServer.Faces.3rd.Edition.May.2010.pdf).  You can read it right there for free.  At least check out the section on navigation... Who knows, maybe fixing your navigation will fix some of your other issues.

Comment: I actually had an epiphany yesterday and it suddenly all came together.  Again -- I've posted previously with similar questions -- it was CDI/JSF confusion (see @Named above).  I hadn't realized the mechanisms for handling request parameters was different for CDI than JSF. In my mind I had lumped it all together.  I'm straight now though.  Thanks for the book reference.  There are several choices out there so your recommendation is helpful.

Comment: Glad you got it.  Epiphanies are cool.